# Monotone convergence of continuous functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Is it true that for a sequence of functions $f_n \in C(K,\mathbb{R})$, where $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ the limit is semicontinuous?

I would say that if it's a monotone decreasing lsequence, then the function is lower semicontinuous and otherwise upper semicontinuous. Is this true?

I was just wondering whether my assumption is correct, although, I would try to prove it then by my own.(I am asking so that I don't waste hours on trying to prove something that is not even true)

Adding: Today, our tutor in university told us that it would be possible to construct a sequence of functions $f_n$ such that the limit would be something like this:

[image]

This one is clearly NOT lower or upper semicontinuous. Are you still sure about our proof? I have some doubts about it, cause maybe it is problematic that $f_n$ is only continuous on a compact set. This is differenct from being continuous and having compact support. Maybe it does not follow from $f_n \in C(K,\mathbb{R})$, that $f_n$ is semicontinuous everywhere? Though, it could be true that my tutor is wrong. Or do you see a way to approximate the function I have drawn by $f_n \in C(K,\mathbb{R})$ functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have confused your cases. Let's say more generally,

- the supremum of a family of continuous functions is lower semicontinuous;
- the infimum of a family of continuous functions is upper semicontinuous.

(Depending on the definitions, you may need to assume that the supremum/infimum are finite everywhere.)

For a monotonic sequence, the limit is the supremum/infimum, so that case is subsumed.

Comment: ah okay. it is probably most easily shown by looking at $f^{-1}(-\infty, a]$ and for a sequence we have $\cap f^{-1}_n(-\infty,a]$ is closed, right? this should show the supremum case.

Comment: I would suggest looking at $f^{-1}((-\infty,a))$ resp. $f^{-1}((a,+\infty))$. I find it much more convenient to work with open sets.

Comment: Hi, maybe you could have a look at my "modified" question?

Comment: It depends on what $K$ is. Let's say the two exceptional points are $0$ and $1$. If either point is isolated, there's no problem, the function is semicontinuous then. If neither point is isolated (and these are indeed exceptional _points_, not small intervals), the function is not semicontinuous on $K$, and hence not a __monotone__ limit of continuous functions. With non-monotonic sequences, you can of course have much much wilder limits. Regarding "Maybe it does not follow ... semicontiuous everywhere", the functions are only defined on $K$, outside $K$, nothing exists.